How to prevent crawl in firebase functions
I have a firebase function lets say that the url is https://test-vx2taqeloc-uc.a.run.app/
I use this function as a http request which can be invoked by anyone.
But someone set up some kind of bot that tries to crawl the url. Some of the exampple urls:
https://test-vx2taqeloc-uc.a.run.app/actuator
https://test-vx2taqeloc-uc.a.run.app/env
https://test-vx2taqeloc-uc.a.run.app/.env
https://test-vx2taqeloc-uc.a.run.app/etc/profile

I ban the IP using Firewall Rules. I don't know if this method works but it doesnt matter because he keeps changing IP whether using a vpn or proxy. He almost invoke the function 100k per month.
Is there any way to prevent this kind of behaviour like rate limiting or something else? And if there is how to set it up?

This is a very broad topic and you may also find that no-one wants to share how they are mitigating attacks because attackers can then implement workarounds. This question thread covers many strategies that you can use to identify common patterns. In the context of Cloud Functions, you will likely want to require ID tokens in the Authorization header, discard unauthenticated or direct (to *.run.app) requests fast, and block clients making multiple unauthenticated requests.
